# Real Analysis - Understanding Definition of Limits of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. Suppose $E \subset X$, $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$, and $p$ is a limit point of $E$. We write $f(x) \rightarrow q$ as $x \rightarrow p$, or $\lim \limits_{x \to p} f(x)= q$  if there is a point $q \in Y$ with the following property: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_Y(f(x), q) < \epsilon$ for all points $x \in E$ for which $0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta$.

I'm not quite able to understand this definition fully. I don't really see the connection between $0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta$ and $d_Y(f(x), q) < \epsilon$; is it saying that if I can find one, it implies the existence of another? I'd really like some help on this definition, and any kind of clarification or Layman's explanation would be tremendously helpful in conceptualizing this. Thank you.

Comment: looks like basic continuity of $f$ in $p\in E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer since it is a 'step away' from understanding

$\tag 1 {\displaystyle \lim _{x\to c}{f(x)}=f(c)}$

It appears that we should answer the basic question,

$\quad$ What does (1) mean?

before tacking more advanced ideas.

In layman's terms, $f$ being continuous at a point $c$ (meaning (1) is satisfied), allows us to say

> We can control the output oscillations of $f$ about $f(c)$ by only
>   looking at the output values of $f$ on points that are mandated to be
>   no further than a fixed distance away from $c$.

In mathematical terms, to 'control oscillations', you must be able face any $\varepsilon \text{ challenge}$, finding a $\delta$ 'mandate' on the domain of $f$ that is an open ball containing $c$.

It might be helpful to understand that for constant functions, you don't have to worry about $f$ output values oscillating at all. Not surprisingly, for any $\varepsilon \text{ challenge}$, you can always respond by choosing $\delta = 1$ (just too easy!).

---

For the OP's original question, the first thing to determine is if $p$ is in the domain of $f$. If it is, and $f(p) = q$, fine and dandy - we are looking at (1); and if $f(p) \ne q$ we might mutter under our breath, 'is that dumb or what?'.

Now if $p \notin E$, we might be tempted to extend $f$ to $E \cup \{p\}$, defining $f(p) = q$. If we do, then again we are looking at (1) and on familiar ground. If you don't want to extend $f$, you should say to yourself,

"Hmmm, interesting..."